# Blender.org is down just for me

Tags: networking, blender

I have a small problem. I am trying to access blender.org but I am unable to do so. This seems to be related to my home network. I tried different browsers on my own laptop, as well as another laptop with no luck. However, using a USB modem, I accessed it normally on my laptop. I am using Chrome on Ubuntu 12.04. In terminal, I tried traceroute belnder.org and this is what I get

> traceroute to blender.org (82.94.226.104), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
>
> 1  . (192.168.1.1)  10.871 ms  11.232 ms  11.483 ms
>
> 2  * * *
>
> 3  172.18.1.157 (172.18.1.157)  95.081 ms  95.414 ms  95.500 ms
>
> 4  172.18.1.10 (172.18.1.10)  61.110 ms 172.18.1.14 (172.18.1.14)  62.364 ms  65.003 ms
>
> 5  172.20.3.37 (172.20.3.37)  89.800 ms  91.130 ms  121.216 ms
>
> 6  172.19.1.22 (172.19.1.22)  87.700 ms 172.19.1.45 (172.19.1.45)  40.092 ms 172.19.1.49 (172.19.1.49)  48.288 ms
>
> 7  172.19.1.125 (172.19.1.125)  75.801 ms 172.19.1.5 (172.19.1.5)  61.225 ms  60.219 ms
>
> 8  pos14-0.palermo9.pal.seabone.net (195.22.198.50)  101.239 ms pos4-0.palermo9.pal.seabone.net (195.22.197.80)  84.861 ms pos10-0.catania4.cat.seabone.net (93.186.129.4)  91.053 ms
>
> 9  xe-8-0-1.franco31.fra.seabone.net (89.221.34.42)  87.616 ms  98.149 ms  104.563 ms
>
> 10  ffm-s2-rou-1041.DE.eurorings.net (134.222.249.25)  104.043 ms  101.470 ms  105.315 ms
>
> 11  ffm-s1-rou-1102.DE.eurorings.net (134.222.229.73)  143.114 ms  147.421 ms  144.489 ms
>
> 12  dssd-s2-rou-1102.DE.eurorings.net (134.222.232.154)  103.794 ms  95.437 ms  89.269 ms
>
> 13  asd2-rou-1022.NL.eurorings.net (134.222.228.137)  94.592 ms  93.848 ms  93.064 ms
>
> 14  asd2-rou-1044.NL.eurorings.net (134.222.199.85)  93.269 ms  91.817 ms  100.703 ms
>
> 15  * * *
>
> 16  * * *
>
> 17  * * *
>
> 18  * * *
>
> 19  * * *
>
> 20  * * *
>
> 21  * * *
>
> 22  * * *
>
> 23  * * *
>
> 24  * * *
>
> 25  * * *
>
> 26  * * *
>
> 27  * * *
>
> 28  * * *
>
> 29  * * *
>
> 30  * * *

Since I am not an expert, I don't understand what this means and I don't know what should I do.

Comment: If you go here: `82.94.213.220`, do you seen "blender.org"?

Comment: No.. It does the same thing... Tries to load, but nothing happens... I should add that today I accessed blender.org easily through the wireless work network... So, it's something wrong with the home network only

Comment: It could be an issue related to your ISP. Give them a call just to see what they say.

Comment: mmm.. I'll see about that.. thank you very much

Comment: I don't know how, but I am able now to access blender.org